# Split string into parts in java to put it in a map

Tags: java, split, hashmap

I have been trying to get all the values from a string and put them in a map in the following manner:

So I have a string which is like this:

```
String cookies = "i=lol;haha=noice;df3=ddtb;"
```

So far I have been trying this out:

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(cookies.split(";")[0].split("=")[0], cookies.split(";")[0].split("=")[1]);
```

But this way I can only put one value in and it is quite long and ugly. Is there any was to due this with regex or a loop?

Comment: It's pretty easy to handle with a for loop, store the value of `cookies.split(";")` in a variable and iterate over its content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a loop to iterate over the key value pairs and put them into the map:

```
String[] cookieArr = cookies.split(";");
for(String cookieString : cookieArr){
  String[] pair = cookieString.split("=");
  if(pair.length < 2){
    continue;
  }
  map.put(pair[0], pair[1]);
}
```

The if is only there to prevent ArrayIndexOutOfBounds expcetions if cookie string is malformed

an alternativ would be using a stream:

```
Arrays.stream(cookies.split(";")).forEach(cookieStr -> map.put(cookieStr.split("=")[0], cookieStr.split("=")[1]));
```

As mentioned by @WJS in the comment, you could use [`map.putIfAbsent(key, vlaue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) instead of [`map.put(key, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) to prevent overriding of values. But in case of cookies it could be a desired behavior to overwrite the old value with the new.

Comment: Aah thank you I shall try it out, also why is pair.length < 2 there like what is its use

Comment: @ShivanshPotdar it could be, the cookie is borken, something like "test" (no = sign) so it should continue and not throw an exception

Comment: Lacking any other direction from the OP you may want to use `map.putIfAbsent()` to handle a duplicate key scenario.

Comment: @WJS thanks, added it as an option to the answer. In a cookie scenario it could be better to overwrite the old value

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this.  It presumes your format is consistent.

- first splits each k/v pair on ";"
- the splits on "=" into key and value.
- and adds to map.
- if duplicate keys show up, the first one encountered takes precedence (if you want the latest value for a duplicate key then use `(a, b)-> b` as the merge lambda.)

```
String cookies = "i=lol;haha=noice;df3=ddtb";
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(cookies.split(";"))
        .map(str -> str.split("=")).collect(Collectors
                .toMap(a -> a[0], a->a[1], (a, b) -> a));
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
df3=ddtb
haha=noice
i=lol
```